# Remove underline from the text in the button (Android)

Tags: android, button, underline

I'm trying to remove the underlining of text from my button. This is the code, where I underline it:

```
buttonNews.setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

I also don't understand why someone put `button.getPaintFlags()` inside the brackets, it works fine with the code above:

```
button.setPaintFlags(button.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Would you please advice how to remove the underlining of the text inside the button programatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They put `button.getPaintFlags()` inside the brackets, to not lose the default/old flag(s).

To remove the `UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG` flag, you can do:

```
button.setPaintFlags( button.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG));
```

This will set all the old flags **except** `Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG`.

Comment: You're welcome. I've already told you, it'll exclude the flag.

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand. So I got 8 from Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG, after ~ Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG I got -9. But there is no such 'static final int' in Paint.java.

Comment: This is an example:  Assuming that for the first time, you do *setPaintFlags(flag1 | flag2 | flag3 | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG );*  then when you do *setPaintFlags( button.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG));* is like doing *setPaintFlags(flag1 | flag2 | flag3 );* => You set all the old flags except UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG. So its not a static value, this is why you get a negative number.

Answer (score -2):

use this for underline text

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>Your Text</u>"));
```

and for remove underline

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("Your Text"));
```

or

```
tv.setText("Your Text");
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I can set the text this way, but it's not underlined.

Comment: Try this

SpannableString content = new        SpannableString(getString(R.string.bike_garage));
            content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
            tvBikeGarage.setText(content);

Comment: Try this button.setPaintFlags( button.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG));